# Gmail's filter for SPAM folder and/or keywords in multiple fields

Tags: gmail, gmail-filters

Gmail's filters are either very weak or I don't understand, how to create just a bit more complex ones.

In particular, how can I create a filter, that will match:

- messages in SPAM folder (as well as in others or only in SPAM folder),
- messages, that contain specified keyword in many fields (i.e. `From` field and message's body).

I'm able to match messages, that contain more than one keyword in given field (for example, to match many keywords in `From` field, I use `one OR two OR three`). But, can I write *one* filter, that will match these keywords in both `From` field and message's body? So, it will apply given filter rule, no matter, if keyword was found in this or that field? Or do I have to write separate filters for each field, which I want to search for matching keywords?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gmail filters may not be sophisticated enough for that. Further, filtering stuff that has the "spam" label may not work reliably. (Filters act when a message arrives; a message marked spam may have been processed before that. You'll even be warned to that effect. Works fine for search, though.)

The best I can come up with based on your question is a filter that looks like this:

> Matches: **(from:(one OR two OR three) (one OR two OR three) in:spam)**
>   Do this: Never mark it as important

When you create the filter you'll essentially put the whole string `from:(one OR two OR three) (one OR two OR three) in:spam` in the `Has the words` field.

There are some flaws. The general text `(one OR two OR three)` could match against the subject (or possibly other places), because there's no way to limit the text search to the body of the message.

More at [Google Support](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7190).